# Disk space unreleased after cleaning up rows from PG table

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I understand space isn't abruptly released (unless one does `TRUNCATE`). But this one looks abnormal to me.

What could be the reason for a postgresql (9.3.10) table not releasing space after having 70% of its records removed?

I have a table called `user_sessions_session`. As the name implies, it stores sessions data for each user of a web app.

It's original size was:

```
              Table               |  Size   | External Size 
----------------------------------+---------+---------------
 user_sessions_session            | 15 GB   | 13 GB
```

I thereafter deleted all user sessions older than 3 months ago. That was the majority of the rows in the table. This was 3 days ago. I just checked the table size again, here's what I see:

```
              Table               |  Size   | External Size 
----------------------------------+---------+---------------
 user_sessions_session            | 15 GB   | 13 GB
```

Moreover, `select * from pg_stat_activity where query like 'autovacuum:%';` reveals no vacuuming is going on at this point.

Btw I've had this same issue with this same sessions table before - it's not a one off.

---

In case it matters, here's the SQL I used to get table sizes (user_sessions_session showed up as number 1 in the list):

```
SELECT                                                         
   relname as "Table",
   pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size(relid)) As "Size",
   pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size(relid) - pg_relation_size(relid)) as "External Size"
   FROM pg_catalog.pg_statio_user_tables ORDER BY pg_total_relation_size(relid) DESC;
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From [the docs,](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/routine-vacuuming.html#vacuum-for-space-recovery)

> **In PostgreSQL, an UPDATE or DELETE of a row does not immediately remove the old version of the row.** This approach is necessary to gain the benefits of multiversion concurrency control (MVCC, see Chapter 13): the row version must not be deleted while it is still potentially visible to other transactions. But eventually, an outdated or deleted row version is no longer of interest to any transaction. The space it occupies must then be reclaimed for reuse by new rows, to avoid unbounded growth of disk space requirements. This is done by running `VACUUM`.

At all. Never. There are no exceptions. When ever you delete a row, you essentially mark it as inactive for your snapshot. Other snapshots started by prior transactions can still see it. This means it's still on disk.

Rows aren't stored in their own file on disk. In order to delete that row, even when you want, you have to essentially rewrite the files stored on disk without that row. `DELETE` does not do this and under *normal* circumstances that's perfectly fine because dead rows that aren't visible to a transaction can be reclaimed *internally* by  a simply `VACUUM`. After being marked for reuse new data can be stored in the heap.

So essentially, only operations that internally cause the table's heap to be rewritten reclaim space. Those operations are:

- `CLUSTER`
- `VACUUM FULL`
- `TRUNCATE`
- `ALTER TABLE` (forms that rewrite the table)

All of these operations require an [`ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html) And, `TRUNCATE` is such a sledge hammer it even [violates MVCC](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/mvcc-caveats.html).

> @EvanCarroll: and so technically, I can actually go out of diskspace even after having removed a ton of rows here? – Hassan Baig 1 min ago

Yea, really and technically and everything else, but let's make one special caveat to the above. If you `DELETE` a bunch of rows and commit they get marked as inactive. When you `VACUUM` the table's heap space gets reclaimed. From that point, to run out of disk space you to either

- Exhaust that reclaimed space on that table's heap because PostgreSQL will just store stuff in that space.
- Or, exhaust a different table's heap.

But yes, *VERY* bad things can happen when you exhaust your disk space. And, they'll happen with *every* MVCC database vendor. Simply, **don't run of disk space**.

Comment: Depends on where those dead rows were allocated. If they were allocated on the tables that are again expanding as normally happens, you'll be totally fine. But PostgreSQL doesn't know how much free space you have on disk. It doesn't check the growth rate of the files internally. It has no system of quota. Disk space is cheap.  I doubt even 1% of the installs require multiple disks (exceed 250 GB in size). So yes, it's very bad but almost never a real concern.

Comment: Ah I see. Just to clarify one thing, I'm not actually going out of disk space - have enough on my system. It's that I'm about to migrate my data from Azure Cloud to AWS. One of the things I have to do is move the postgresql DB as well (~40 GB in size). I thought it's a good time to run some clean up and reduce the size I have to migrate. So I cleaned my 3 largest tables (removed dead users). I expected the DB to halve, but it didn't happen. Thus, this question.

Comment: Have a look at [pg_repack](https://github.com/reorg/pg_repack/) for helping reclaim space with less impact (fewer heavy-weight locks) if minimizing disruption to your production system is a concern.

Comment: @bma: on the surface of it, it looks like something I'd like to try. Have you any experience with it? Pros and Cons?

Comment: Yep, I've used it. It is an excellent tool. No real cons I can think of, whenever I used it I was careful to execute it during slacker periods of the day/night in the production databases.