# Time taken by VACUUM FULL to reclaim space

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, maintenance, vacuum

After receiving some [insightful guidance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/187044/disk-space-unreleased-after-cleaning-up-rows-from-pg-table) in a previous post here, I'm going to run `VACUUM FULL` on 4 PostgreSQL 9.3.10 tables. Table sizes are:

1) `links_publicreply`: ~30M rows, 9 columns, 3 indexes (types: int, timestamp, char, bool)

2) `links_reply`: ~25M rows, 8 columns, 6 indexes (types: int, text, timestamp, char)

3) `links_link`: ~8M rows, 14 columns, 3 indexes (types: int, text, dbl precision, timestamp, char bool)

4) `links_user_sessions`: ~2M rows, 7 columns, 4 indexes (types: int, text, timestamp, inet)

This is my first attempt at reclaiming disk space. It's a busy server of a local social networking website. No time is actually "downtime". But the least busy is ~4:00 AM, so that the window I'll use.

Speaking from experience, can you guys form any opinion on how long VACUUM FULL would take for the 4 tables I pointed out? I'd like to put up a "under maintenance till xx:xx:xx" message on the website while it's happening. I know no one can be sure, but is this deterministic enough for you to form a ballpark opinion?

Secondly, just so that we're on the same page, the commands I'd be running on psql are simply `VACUUM (FULL, VERBOSE, ANALYZE) link_publicreply;` (and so on), correct? Don't want to screw it up.

Comment: It's more like a question on the other question, but: how do you plan to move your DB from Azure to AWS?  By taking a dump here and restore there?  In this case, `VACUUM FULL` won't give any advantage.  If via setting up some replication (streaming or similar), then it might make sense.

Comment: @dezso: yes just via `pg_dump`. I was hoping this would lower the size of the dump I have to move (I halved these tables). Wouldn't that be an advantage in itself?

Comment: It doesn't have an effect on the dump size.  On the other hand, taking the dump will be possibly faster - not sure how much faster though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> It's a busy server of a local social networking website. No time is actually "downtime".

So `VACUUM FULL` is going to be a problem since it takes an exclusive lock on each table it processes. Consider the community tool [**`pg_repack`**](https://github.com/reorg/pg_repack) instead which achieves the same without exclusive locks.

Related:

- [VACUUM returning disk space to operating system](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/37028/vacuum-returning-disk-space-to-operating-system/37032#37032)

None of this affects the size of backups, since those do not include dead rows to begin with.

Comment: In other words, by taking `pg_dump` and transferring it, I would already have reclaimed the space in my new set up?

Comment: @HassanBaig: That's correct. A dump/restore cycle produces a database in pristine condition without any bloat. It's not exactly "reclaiming" space, since the additional space is never claimed to begin with ...